# Did Luke Castellan make it to Elysium as Annabeth said he would?

Tags: percy-jackson

Because, you know, Luke was evil, and Hazel says that the judges pull the thoughts from your head and all that. I'm not sure if Luke did enough good to get to Elysium.

Did Luke Castellan make it to Elysium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Presumably, but we don't know for certain.**

At the end of *The Last Olympian*, we see this:

> The Fates themselves took Luke's body.
>   I hadn't seen the old ladies in years, since I'd witnessed them snip a life thread at a roadside fruit stand when I was twelve.
>   [...]
>   They gathered up Luke's body, now wrapped in a white-and-green shroud, and began carrying it out of the throne room.
>   "Wait," Hermes said.
>   The messenger god...
>   [...]
>   Hermes unwrapped Luke's face and kissed his forehead. He murmured some words in Ancient Greek—a final blessing.
>   <sub>*Percy Jackson & the Olympians, book 5: The Last Olympian*, chapter 20: "We Win Fabulous Prizes"</sub>

This would seem to indicate that Hermes is okay with where Luke is headed, and that he's a pretty special dude since the Fates came to collect him and not Thanatos.

We don't see anything about Luke's future later on - we don't see him in the Underworld at all.

But Luke died a hero, and the gods knew that. I doubt that he would have gotten anything but Elysium.

For a comparison with *The Heroes of Olympus*:

> Just like Hazel Levesque would have gotten Elysium if she had not claimed responsibility on her mother's behalf, even though she was guilty of raising Alcyoneus, so to Luke: even though he helped to make Kronos rise, he died on behalf of the gods. He died a hero, and that's important.

But really, we don't know for certain, since we don't see him again.

Comment: So he could have made Asphodel? Of would the judges have said "Too much evil" like they said stuff like that to Hazel?

Comment: Yes - either Asphodel or Elysium, but Elysium is more likely.

Answer (score -1):

I think at best he would get is asphodel..that too maybe...he was too much manipulative, cruel, heartless, pedophile and so on... he literally had 2 good moments in his life and one of them to stop his mistake from causing even more damage..so many lives lost to him directly and indirectly

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you [edit] in some quotes from the books to help motivate your answer a bit more?